# How to check, and list which extensions of a python script used "extensions" are already installed or still need to be installed?

Tags: python, dependencies

Some scripts use some additional stuff which need to be installed on machine, which running on python script.

Is there one script, or like this, which which can check all python scripts, located in one folder for:

- output a list of what additional software the scripts need to be installed on this machine
- check against the created list, which software already installed
- check against the created list, which software need still to be installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python you can use [pipreqs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs) to get list of modules in the "standard" `requirements.txt` file format and then use `pip` to install the modules/packages `pip install -r requirements.txt` (this will of course install only modules that are not already installed).

Comment: That sounds intresting. THX