# How to check, and list, which external dependencies a bash script has?

Tags: bash, dependencies

**Output a list of what commands the script use**
Perhaps its possible to create a list of used command by about follow:

```
set -n file_which_need_to_check.sh > found _commands.txt
```

Or by about the follow:

```
compgen -c file_which_need_to_check.sh > found_commands.txt
```

Or by the follow:

shellcheck -x or like this:

- https://www.shellcheck.net/
- https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck

**It is known and not asked for the follow:**

A list including path oh all bash files of a folder, can get on follow way:

```
find \ordnerpfad -type f
```

Its possible to test whether a system supports a particular command:

```
compgen -ac | grep searchstr
```

Comment: Unmaintained and possibly outdated, you could nevertheless test or at least borrow some ideas from https://github.com/eberk/loker

Comment: Related: [How to check, and list which extensions of a python script used "extensions" are already installed or still need to be installed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/627371)

Comment: How would you know that an external tool, such as `yq` or `rename` would be the correct such tool for what your scripts need? Why would you want to automate this task instead of just documenting the dependencies, just like ordinary developers would do when they distribute their code to a wider audience.  It is not the script's responsibility to care about 3rd party tools on other people's systems.

Comment: There are at least three different and incompatible variants of utilities called `yq` and `rename`.  That was my point with my previous comment.  Even with standard utilities such as `sed` and `awk`, how would you detect which of the _variants_ of these the script actually needs? What if the script depends on undocumented quirks of a certain utility on a certain operating system?

Comment: I simplified the question now.

Comment: @Alfred.37 you completely removed the main part of the question! That's not a simplification. That's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such tooling (as far as I'm aware of, and as far as I could imagine). You need to run the script to know. Especially large, complicated scripts often detect what is available on a system (e.g. `ggrep`/`egrep`/`bsdgrep`/`perl`/…, or `gmake` vs `make` vs `bsdmake` vs `ninja`), and do different things.

From a software perspective, the commands that need to be run are sometimes (often, if you're looking at installers, and system administration tools) "built" within the script, so without running the source code, you don't even know the executable that would be run.

So, to know that, you either run, or you would kind of need to build a complete code analyzer for a shell – a very complicated endeavor that I can't imagine someone doing, as all you'd avoid is running badly-documented shell scripts until they fail (which you could nowadays do, basically for free, on a containerized or VM clone of your actual system).
Reimplementing all the problematic scripts so you know what you're depending on would probably be worlds easier than to write such an analyzer.

This all boils down to doing good software engineering as a script author and clearly stating your requirements somewhere.

> Some scripts use additional tools, like xdotool, which must be installed on a machine in order to run the scripts.

Well, I hope you're not randomly executing scripts you find in some dark corner of the internet! Usually, scripts come in some form of packaged software.
For example, and I really picked one by random from my /usr/bin, the `/usr/bin/virt-copy-out` script on my system came from the `libguestfs` Fedora package. If I ask my system what that package depends on, there's a longer list, including `bash` (obviously, it's a bash script, it won't run without bash), `coreutils` (cp, sort, find…), `less`, `tar`…. 
So, the authors of that package (and the script) took the time to figure out which things this package, including the scripts it contains, need. That's (one|the) reason why you want distro packages! If any of these was missing by the time I tried to install that package, my package manager would have automatically installed all these dependencies for me.

Comment: This dont fit the question.

Comment: @Alfred.37 yes, the question was substantially rewritten since it was asked, it seems the important parts of the original question were removed. Please compare the version of the question from the 9th of November, when this answer was posted, to its current form. You'll notice the author has quite slaughtered their own question.